# Relaciones con Laravel 5.8 - Obtener solo registros que existen

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy intentando hacer relaciones con las tablas en Laravel, pero a pesar de que las voy comprendiendo más no consigo hacer esto.

**Mi tabla mesas**

| id | name | zona |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Llevar | 2 |
| 2 | Mesa 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Mesa 2 | 2 |

**Mi tabla orders**

| id | preparado | ticket | mesa_id | producto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021178 | 1 | Pizza carbonara |
| 2 | 0 | 2021179 | 2 | Refresco |
| 2 | 0 | 2021179 | 2 | Café |
| 2 | 0 | 2021179 | 2 | Pizza romana |

Como veis la tabla `orders` tiene un campo que se llama preparado, entonces lo primero que quiero hacer es sacar las mesas que tienen un pedido sin preparar que es = 0. Luego dentro de cada mesa quiero sacar los pedidos que hay sin preparar pero agrupados por ticket, es decir que pueda imprimir el número de ticket como titulo, pero iterar los productos que tiene ese ticket debajo del titulo.

Para sacar las mesas que están con un pedido sin preparar es decir que están activas hago lo siguiente.

```
$mesas = Mesas::with('pedidos')->join('orders', 'mesas.id', '=', 'orders.mesa_id')
        ->select('mesas.mesa', 'mesas.id', 'orders.mesa_id', 'orders.tipo_pedido', 'orders.preparado')
        ->groupBy('mesas.mesa', 'mesas.id', 'orders.mesa_id', 'orders.tipo_pedido', 'orders.preparado')
        ->where('orders.preparado', 0)
        ->where('orders.tipo_pedido', 1)->get();
```

**Mi modelo Mesas**

```
public function pedidos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'id', 'mesa_id');  
}
```

**Luego en mi vista**

```
@foreach ($mesas as $item)
  <li>
   {{ $item->mesa }}
  </li>
     @foreach ($item->pedidos as $peds)
       <div>{{ $peds->ticket }}</div>
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Si me saca las mesas que están con preparado = 0 pero las tengo que agrupar para que no se dupliquen, pero no consigo sacar una vez el ticket y debajo de eso iterar los productos que tiene ese ticket.

Comment: Podrías ver de hacer un SELECT DISTINCT. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258500/980631

Comment: Hola @boctulus y probe hacer un distinct, a no ser que lo que dices seal algo diferente. De todos modos eso para que seria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien al final he conseguido lo que quiero:

Primero busco las mesas activas en un pedido con el campo preparado = 0:

```
public function cocina()
    {
        $mesas = Mesas::with('pedidos')->join('orders', 'mesas.id', '=', 'orders.mesa_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('order.tickets as Tickets'))
        ->select('mesas.mesa', 'mesas.id', 'orders.mesa_id')
        ->groupBy('mesas.mesa', 'mesas.id', 'orders.mesa_id')
        ->where('orders.preparado', 0)->get();
        //dd($mesas);
        return view('cocina')->with(['mesas' => $mesas]);
    }
```

En mi modelo Mesas, saco todos los productos asociados a esa mesa:

```
public function pedidos()
{
 return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'mesa_id')->where('preparado', 0);  
}
```

En mi vista.

```
//Primero itero las mesas activas
@foreach ($mesas as $item)
  <li>
    {{ $item->mesa }}
  </li>
    //Después itero los pedidos de las mesas y los agrupo por ticket con $key para un arreglo asociativo
    @foreach ($item->pedidos->groupBy('ticket') as $key => $peds)
       <div class="modulOrder">
         //Imprimo el número de ticket
         <b>{{ $key }}</b>
         //Itero el contenido del ticket
         @foreach ($peds as $item5)
            <div>{{ $item5->producto }}</div>
         @endforeach 
       </div> 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```